# No option for ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ado, visual-studio-2019

just trying to set my data access layer up but there's no option for the ADO.NET data model despite having Entity Framework 6.3.0 installed as a NuGet package, as well as Entity Framework 6 tools installed in Visual Studio 2019. Target framework is .NET 4.7.2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by: There's no option for the ADO.NET data model? Menu option?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I was making a 'Class Library (.NET Standard)', if you make a 'Class Library (.NET Framework)' project you should see the ADO.NET Entity Data Model.